# Run line at node script end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've written a script that recursively asynchronously modifies js files in a directory. It's made up of a `search(dirname)` function which searches a directory for js files, and a `modify(filename)` which does the modifying.

```
let totalFilesSearched = 0;

const search = (dir) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, list) => {
        if (err) return;
        list.forEach((filename) => {
            const filepath = path.join(dir, filename);
            if (filename.endsWith('.js')) {
                modify(filepath);
            } else if (fs.lstatSync(filepath).isDirectory()) {
                search(filepath);
            }
        })
    });
}

const modify = (filename) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // ... my modification code ...
        totalFilesSearched++;
    });
}

search(args[0])
console.log(`Total files searched: ${totalFilesSearched}`);
```

I want to print out the `totalFilesSearched` at the end of my script but because my code is asynchronous, it just prints `Total files searched: 0` right away.

Does anyone know how I'd wait until the script is about to end to print this out? I'm having trouble because both my `search()` and `modify()` functions are asynchronous.

Comment: Use the promise

Comment: Promise is your friend

Comment: Not sure how I'd use it here as both my search and modfiy functions are async

Comment: That's what it's for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Promises instead, and then call `console.log` when everything is resolved. Use `promisify` to turn the callbacks into promises:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

const search = (dir) => (
  readDir(dir).then((list) => (
    Promise.all(list.map((filename) => {
      const filepath = path.join(dir, filename);
      if (filename.endsWith('.js')) {
        return modify(filepath); // recursively return the promise
      } else if (fs.lstatSync(filepath).isDirectory()) {
        return search(filepath); // recursively return the promise
      }
    }))
  ))
  .catch(err => void 0)
);

const modify = (filename) => (
  readFile(filename, 'utf8')
    .then((data) => {
      // other code
      totalFilesSearched++;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
)

search(args[0])
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Total files searched: ${totalFilesSearched}`);
  });
```

Comment: What errors? Are the promises being chained correctly?

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless the `readDir` call is not being implicitly returned. Are you sure the `search` definition line looks like `const search = (dir) => (`, without the bracket? (if using an arrow function, if the first statement is going to be returned, use parentheses or nothing instead of `{}` brackets with a `return` statement)

Comment: changed it but then the `.then()` is getting called immediately

Comment: Which `then`? You mean `list` is undefined?

Comment: No the last `.then()`, the "Total files..." is getting printed out right away

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171854/discussion-between-certainperformance-and-markscode).

Comment: btw. There was an easier solution to my question. Just use `process.on('exit', callback_function_to_execute_at_end)`

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

Just use `process.on('exit', callback_function_to_execute_at_end)`

Its built into node, your callback will get executed right before the process exits.